# Can this matrix group be obtained from $(\mathbb R,+)$ and $(\mathbb R^*,\cdot)$?

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

I have stumbled upon this group of matrices in an old midterm:
$$G=\{
\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b \\
  0 & \frac1a \\
\end{pmatrix}; a,b\in\mathbb R, a\ne0
\}.$$
The students were asked to show that this is a group (under matrix multiplication).

It is easy to notice that this group contains two subgroups
\begin{align*}
H_1&=\{
\begin{pmatrix}
  a & 0 \\
  0 & \frac1a \\
\end{pmatrix}; a\in\mathbb R^*
\}\\
H_2&=\{
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & b \\
  0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}; b\in\mathbb R
\}
\end{align*}
such that $H_1 \cong (\mathbb R^*, \cdot)$ and $H_2\cong (\mathbb R,+)$.

> I wonder whether there is some group theoretic construction using which we can obtain $G$ from $H_1$ and $H_2$. (I.e., some kind of construction which, given the two groups $(\mathbb R^*,\cdot)$ and $(\mathbb R,+)$ returns a group isomorphic to $G$.)

It is not very difficult to see that:

- Every element $g\in G$ can be expressed in exactly one way as $g=h_1h_2$ where $h_1\in H_1$ and $h_2\in H_2$.
  $$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a & 0 \\
    0 & \frac1a
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & b \\
    0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a & ab \\
    0 & \frac1a
  \end{pmatrix}
  $$
- Of course, the same is true for expression of the form $g=h_2h_1$ with $h_i\in H_i$. (We can simply take such expression form $g^{-1}$ and invert it.)
- $H_2$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, it is kernel of the homomorphism $\begin{pmatrix}
    a & b \\
    0 & \frac1a
  \end{pmatrix}\mapsto a$ from $G$ to $\mathbb R^*$.

Other than that, I did not notice anything special about $H_1$ and $H_2$; so it is quite possible that the answer is no. But since here we see two well-known groups as a subgroup of a relatively simple matrix group, I still thought that this is worth asking.

Comment: What you write just means that the group is the semidirect product of those subgroups. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft he needs that there is a section of the map, not just that there is a s.e.s. for it, but that's the right conclusion.

Comment: @AdamHughes No, he needs precisely what he has, since he has two subgroups generating the group, intersecting trivially and one of them normal. No need for any sections.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Technically, the OP hasn't pointed out that they intersect trivially, but it's not very difficult to show.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft ah, I thought you were focusing on the last point in particular since there was no intersection bit.

Comment: @Arthur Well, it is part of the "unique" he writes.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Oh, I missed that one word.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Of course, you are right. And I should have noticed that. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

1. $H_2$ normal
2. $H_1\cap H_2 = \{I_2\}$, where $I_2$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix
3. Every $g \in H$ is of the form $h_1h_2$ with $h_1\in H_1, h_2\in H_2$

which is the definition of the (inner) [semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) $H_2\rtimes H_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is a section of the short exact sequence

> $$0\to(\Bbb R,+)\to (G,*)\to (\Bbb R^*,\cdot)\to 0$$

this is a [semi-direct product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) of the groups $(\Bbb R, +)$ and $(\Bbb R^*, \cdot )$. The bottom of the section on outer semi-direct products I linked discusses the construction. (This is not an outer semi-direct product since they are subgroups of the big group, but that's where the section statement is)